# i am facing flutter webview issue

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new in a flutter. I m facing an issue in flutter_webview here is my code IDK what's wrong with it. I write this code with the help of StackOverflow and an official plugin. my HTML files working fine

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
class Licences extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LicencesState createState() => _LicencesState();
}
class _LicencesState extends State<Licences> {
  WebViewController webViewController;
  String filePath = 'files/PrivacyPolicy.html';
 loadHtml() async {
   String data = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
   webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(data,
           mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Open-Source Licences'),
      ),
       body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: '',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
             webViewController = controller;
            loadHtml();
           },
         );
      }),
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what is wrong with it? What are you expecting to happen and what is happening?

Comment: @StoyanMilev it not appear in my app

Comment: output is not appear. i try to show my local HTML file in webview

Comment: Have you added the file or the folder `files/PrivacyPolicy.html` to your `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: @StoyanMilev yes i added in .yaml

Comment: Can you add `print(data)` in `loadHtml()` and add it to your question?

Comment: E/flutter (17019): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 470)
E/flutter (17019): #0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1783:7)
E/flutter (17019): #1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:321:42)
E/flutter (17019): #2      Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:62:20)
E/flutter (17019): #3      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:77:19)
E/flutter (17019): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: Can you provide your HTML file as from the log it seems like the problem is within it?

Comment: ok i got it. thanks for help